# How to calculate the distribution of the number of trips over a day using MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, average, distribution

I have a DB with historical data about different trips during a year. I need to know the distribution of the number of trips over a day (in Java). For instance:

```
00:00-01:00: 1, 01:00-02:00: 0, ..., 23:00-00:00: 4
```

Note: The output should be in JSON format.

I'm interested in the optimal approach (steps) to solve this task. At the moment, I plan to solve it in the following way:

```
1) Create List<Hashtable<String,Integer>> (Hashtable has 24 keys, each corresponding to one hour interval over the day). 
2) Connect to DB and run SQL query in order to download all trips. 
3) Run through ResultSet and add 1 to the corresponding day and time slot in List<Hashtable<String,Integer>>
4) Close connection with DB 
5) Create Hashtable<String,Integer> with 24 keys, each corresponding to one hour interval over the day.
6) Run over List<Hashtable<String,Integer>>. Calculate an average number of trips per each hourly interval over all days and save results in Hashtable<String,Integer>. 
7) Convert Hashtable<String,Integer> to JSON as follows:
```

Sample JSON output:

```
{"00:00-01:00": 1, "01:00-02:00": 0, ..., "23:00-00:00": 4}
```

**Maybe I can do the same task using SQL with AVERAGE?**

Comment: Grouping you data by date with an SQL query should not be difficult. Can you please post how your table (or your tables) looks which store said data? A `DESCRIBE Tablename` output would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL aggregate queries are great for this.

This query gives you the number of days represented in your database last year.

```
                    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(triptime)))
                      FROM trip_hour
                     WHERE YEAR(triptime) = YEAR(NOW()-1)
```

This gives you the number of trips in each hour-long slot.

```
 SELECT HOUR(a.triptime) AS trip_hour, 
        COUNT(*) AS trip_count
   FROM trip 
  WHERE YEAR(triptime) = YEAR(NOW()-1)
  GROUP BY HOUR(triptime)
  ORDER BY HOUR(triptime)
```

Finally this gives the average number of trips per day in each hour slot, combining the two above queries.

```
 SELECT HOUR(a.triptime) AS trip_hour, 
        COUNT(*) AS trip_count,
        COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE(triptime)))
                      FROM trip_hour
                     WHERE YEAR(triptime) = YEAR(NOW()-1)) AS trip_avg
   FROM trip 
  WHERE YEAR(triptime) = YEAR(NOW()-1)
  GROUP BY HOUR(triptime)
  ORDER BY HOUR(triptime)
```

This will give you a 24-row resultset to download, rather than a gazillion trips.

All kinds of sophistication in the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` clauses can be employed. But this should get you started.